# Creating a DataFrame from a complex nested dictionary (various depths) and lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have an API call that responds with a nested dictionary of varying levels.  I apologize in advance for any misused terminology or anything as, while I have a good bit of experience with data wrangling in general, complex dictionaries are not something I am too familiar with.  I'm trying to create a data frame that has each level and attribute as a columns.  Level values for columns 'Level0', 'Level1', etc., are values for the '@name' key of each level in the dictionary.  Attribute column names are the values for the '@name' key, with values for those columns in the '@value'.

Here's a snippet of the dictionary:

```
dct={'@id': '21',
 '@name': 'Top Level',
 '@hasChildren': 'true',
 'level': [{'@id': '22',
   '@name': 'Asset1',
   '@hasChildren': 'true',
   'level': [{'@id': '530',
     '@name': 'Sub Asset1-1',
     'attributes': {'attribute': [{'@attributeId': '1581',
        '@name': 'Grouping',
        '@value': 'Tall'},
       {'@attributeId': '1141',
        '@name': 'Asset Reporting',
        '@value': 'Public'},
       {'@attributeId': '981',
        '@name': 'Unit',
        '@value': 'Tons'}]}},
    {'@id': '101',
     '@name': 'Asset2',
     '@hasChildren': 'true',
     'level': [{'@id': '123',
       '@name': 'Sub Asset2-1',
       '@hasChildren': 'true',
       'level': [{'@id': '1061',
         '@name': 'Store 2-1-1',
         '@hasChildren': 'true',
         'level': [{'@id': '205',
           '@name': 'Shelf 23',
           'attributes': {'attribute': [{'@attributeId': '581',
              '@name': 'Type',
              '@value': 'Shirt'},
             {'@attributeId': '1161',
              '@name': 'Region',
              '@value': 'USA'},
             {'@attributeId': '1261',
              '@name': 'Area_Grouping',
              '@value': 'East Coast'},
             {'@attributeId': '1581',
              '@name': 'Grouping',
              '@value': 'Short'},
             {'@attributeId': '1141',
              '@name': 'Asset Reporting',
              '@value': 'Consolidated'},
             {'@attributeId': '981',
              '@name': 'Unit',
              '@value': 'Feet'}]}},
          {'@id': '213',
           '@name': 'Shelf 49',
           'attributes': {'attribute': [{'@attributeId': '581',
              '@name': 'Type',
              '@value': 'Pants'},
             {'@attributeId': '1161',
              '@name': 'Region',
              '@value': 'USA'},
             {'@attributeId': '1261',
              '@name': 'Area_Grouping',
              '@value': 'West Coast'},
             {'@attributeId': '1581',
              '@name': 'Grouping',
              '@value': 'Short'},
             {'@attributeId': '1141',
              '@name': 'Asset Reporting',
              '@value': 'Consolidated'},
             {'@attributeId': '981',
              '@name': 'Unit',
              '@value': 'Feet'}]}}
'attributes': {'attribute': {'@attributeId': '841',
   '@name': 'Consolidated Reporting',
   '@value': 'Consolidated'}}}
```

I'm trying to end up with a data frame that looks like this (truncated attributes due to the size format):

```
Level0    |Level1   |Level2     |Level3     |Level4     
|Grouping|Asset Reporting
Top Level |     |       |       |       |    |       
Top Level |Asset1   |Sub Asset1-1   |       |       |Tall    |Public     
Top Level |Asset2   |Sub Asset2-1   |Store 2-1-1    |Shelf 23   |    |Consolidated   
Top Level |Asset2   |Sub Asset2-1   |Store 2-1-1    |Shelf 49   |Short   |Consolidated
```

After many different efforts that I now can't recreate, I started to get something from help from [here](https://rowannicholls.github.io/python/advanced/dictionaries.html) (see 1.6), but I still just end up with a dictionary that I cannot figure out how to work into a data frame.

```
def get_all_values(obj, level=0):
    """Walk through a dictionary of dicts and lists."""
    if type(obj) is dict:
        for key, value in obj.items():
            if type(value) in [dict, list]:
                print('\t' * level, key, sep='')
                level = level + 1
                get_all_values(value, level)
                level = level - 1
            else:
                print('\t' * (level), key, ': ', value, sep='')
    elif type(obj) is list:
        for i, element in enumerate(obj):
            if type(element) in [dict, list]:
                print('\t' * level, i, sep='')
                level = level + 1
                get_all_values(element, level)
                level = level - 1
            else:
                print('\t' * (level), element, sep='')
    else:
        raise ValueError
```

I have also tried using a combination of .explode() and pd.Series after putting it into a data frame, but feel it is probably best to do more work before a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data has invalid syntax. I closed the brackets but I get `Asset2` as a child of `Asset1`... Anyway this isn't relevant for the logic implied.

Using a recursive function is the right approach:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_all_values(obj):
    res = []
    
    def get_level(obj, level=0, r={}):
        if type(obj) is dict:
            if n:=obj.get('@value', obj.get('@name')):
                r[f'Level{level}'] = n
            if l:=obj.get('level', obj.get('attributes', obj.get('attribute'))):
                r.update(get_level(l, level+1, r.copy()))
        elif type(obj) is list:
            bottom = False
            for element in obj:
                if isinstance(element, dict):
                    if '@value' in element:
                        r[element['@name']] = element['@value']
                        bottom = True
                    else:
                        r[f'Level{level}'] = element.get('@name')
                        r.update(get_level(element, level, r.copy()))
            if bottom:
                res.append(r)
        return r

    get_level(obj)
    return res

print(pd.DataFrame(get_all_values(dct)))
```

Output:

```
      Level0  Level1        Level2 Grouping Asset Reporting  Unit        Level3       Level4    Level5   Type Region Area_Grouping
0  Top Level  Asset1  Sub Asset1-1     Tall          Public  Tons           NaN          NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN           NaN       
1  Top Level  Asset1        Asset2    Short    Consolidated  Feet  Sub Asset2-1  Store 2-1-1  Shelf 23  Shirt    USA    East Coast       
2  Top Level  Asset1        Asset2    Short    Consolidated  Feet  Sub Asset2-1  Store 2-1-1  Shelf 49  Pants    USA    West Coast
```